# update not using index postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to optimize a query.  The table that I'm updating, vwml_premelissa, has 3.5mil records.  I have a second table (50k records) that specifies which records need to be updated.

There is a unique index on vwml_premelissa on the "vin" column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pkey_vwml_premelissa
  ON extras.vwml_premelissa
  USING btree
  (vin COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

The query...

```
update extras.vwml_premelissa 
    set suppress = 'THREE' where vin in (select vin from extras.vwml_threes)
```

Is taking over an hour on my dev box.  When I do an explain on the query I get

```
Update on vwml_premelissa  (cost=1837.07..412393.58 rows=52892 width=182)
  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1837.07..412393.58 rows=52892 width=182)
        Hash Cond: ((vwml_premelissa.vin)::text = (vwml_threes.vin)::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on vwml_premelissa  (cost=0.00..219004.32 rows=3685132 width=176)
        ->  Hash  (cost=865.92..865.92 rows=52892 width=24)
              ->  Seq Scan on vwml_threes  (cost=0.00..865.92 rows=52892 width=24)
```

Why does postgres insist on doing a seq scan of vwml_premelissa instead of using the index to locate the records it needs to update?

postgres 9.2 windows

Comment: Are your statistics up to date (`analyze`)? You might also try a join instead of the `IN`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DBMS expert, and it's been a few years since I spent any time in PostgreSQL, but in some RDBMSs, queries don't always use indexes if the engine believes it's going to have to perform a table scan anyway. For example, if `vwml_threes` has high cardinality and a number of rows similar to that in `vwml_premelissa`, then the engine may decide it's just as efficient to do a table scan as to try to perform index lookups for each record in `vwml_threes`.

You can try including additional criteria, as by chunking by date, and then iterating over those chunks until your full update is complete. Obviously, those criteria need to be indexed as well if you want to see a performance gain, so your total query cost is going to include adding missing indexes, which may not make sense for a one-time query.

I'd be interested to hear if this explanation applies to PostgreSQL--it's quite possible I'm mistaken.